# Does this PHP code crash Apache for anyone else?

Tags: php, apache, crash

```
preg_match_all('/(a)*/', str_repeat('a', 1000), $matches);
```

(edit: change the regexp a bit to make it simpler while still crashing)

I ran it on PHP 5.3.5 with Apache 2.0 and it crashes the server. If I change 339 to 338 it doesn't crash anymore, so it seems like a bug to me. I tried reporting it to http://bugs.php.net/ but it's down. Is this a PHP bug? Does it crash for anyone else?

**Edit:** Changing the code to

```
preg_match_all('/(?:a)*/', str_repeat('a', 339), $matches);
```

allows for a longer string before crashing.
If it doesn't crash, try increasing the string length by a factor of 10 or 100 as it may be a memory issue and you may have more memory.

**Edit 2:** the crash is a complete process crash, on Windows 7 I get the "End task" message instantaneously after execution.

**Edit 3:** if the crash is due to too much backtracing, and the above example clearly can cause it, the following should not:

```
preg_match('/[^"\']*(;|$)/',
               str_repeat('x', 1000), $matches);
```

This is my actual code that's crashing. It's simply meant to split multiple SQL queries by `;`, while allowing `;` inside single or double quotes. Why is this causing so much backtracing, and how can I fix it?

Comment: crashes as u get an error? memory limit maybe?

Comment: post the relevant sections of your Apache errorlog

Comment: ini_set('max_execution_time', 1500);
ini_set("memory_limit", "32M");

Comment: didnt seem to crash mine. Sorry

Comment: It works for me and returns `2`. It executes very quickly, and `memory_get_peak_usage()` reports only 327552 bytes used, so that's not it. This is on CLI PHP 5.3.2.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx there is nothing related to a crash in apache/logs/error.log

Comment: @Sahal tried your suggestion with 32M, 128M and 512M all with the same result of instant crash on execution.

Comment: still dont know what crash means

Comment: Ah, Windows. My guess would be something wrong with your build/it's PCRE library. Definitely local to your config. Also, not sure why you are editing the crash condition or telling us to run it 100 times longer -- ideally you want to isolate the *simplest/shortest* thing that makes it crash and trace from there.

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't memory or execution time...

```
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', 10000);
```

Feel free to **decrease** the 10000 to a different value if necessary. For more information, see http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php.

If you feel like testing where it crashes:

```
<?php

ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', 10000);

for ( $i = 1; $i < 65535; $i++ )
{
  echo $i . PHP_EOL;
  preg_match_all('/(a)*/', str_repeat('a', $i), $matches);
}

?>
```

Comment: I tried it with 10 000, 100 000 and 1 000 000 all with the same result of instantaneous crash. But why is it backtracking? Shouldn't /(a)*/ greedily match all the text, and return really fast?

Comment: @manixrock - You can read about it here: [http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: Ok, decreasing it makes more sense. With 500 it doesn't crash for 1000-chars string. But I still don't understand why it's backtracking. The match is greedy, and it should match all on the first run, then stop.

Comment: @manixrock - Read the article I linked to above. It explains what backtracking is. It should make sense when you're done reading it.

Comment: @Francois Deschenes - I knew about that problem with regexp, but I thought preg_match_all() wouldn't backtrack between the different match parts. But this does not explain why my main query, which shouldn't allow for backtracing, still crashes. I'll edit my main post in a minute...

Comment: @manixrock - That 3rd regular expression behaves exactly like the 1st. It's using to much stack space and causing PHP to segfault.

Comment: @Francois Deschenes - I don't get why it's using too much stack space? This one FORCES it to match `(;|$)` at the end of each match. How should I change it so it does what is's supposed to?